# D3js svg does not render on first page load

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, component, lightning-components, d3

I have a custom visualisation inside a lightning component which uses d3js.

My svg is well rendered whenever I hard refresh the record page containing the custom component, but does not display when I land on the page initially.

Code:

test.cmp

```
<aura:component  implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.d3 + '/d3.min.js'}"
              styles="{!$Resource.d3 + '/d3.css'}"
              afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <div aura:id="map" id="map" class="page-section"></div>
</aura:component>
```

testController.js

```
({

doInit: function (component, event, helper) { 
  
var jsonCircles = [
   { "x_axis": 30, "y_axis": 30, "radius": 20, "color" : "green" },
   { "x_axis": 70, "y_axis": 70, "radius": 20, "color" : "purple"},
   { "x_axis": 110, "y_axis": 100, "radius": 20, "color" : "red"}];
 
 var svgContainer = d3.select("div#map").append("svg")
                                     .attr("width", 200)
                                    .attr("height", 200);
 
var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
                         .data(jsonCircles)
                          .enter()
                          .append("circle");

var circleAttributes = circles
                       .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x_axis; })
                       .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y_axis; })
                       .attr("r", function (d) { return d.radius; })
                       .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });
                    
}
})
```

Comment: This might not make much sense, have you tried with [Disabling Caching Setting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/debug_disable_caching.htm).

Comment: @Raul thanks for the good idea but did not work unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue:

On first page load, salesforce  can render your component's html multiple times to manage facets.

I fixed my issue by using `d3.selectAll()` instead of `d3.select()` and subsequently added an svg to all the divs rendered